# difference between current and database stored date and time

Tags: php, mysql

i have column in database that stores `date,time and duration`.

```
<form action="exam_schedule.php" method="post">
    <input type="date" name="date" value="">
    <input type="time" name="time" value="">
    <input type="number" name="duration" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

it stores date perfectly in database but don't mention AM and PM with time. 
I want calculate the difference between current date and time with value stored in database.

```
$query="SELECT * from exam_schedule";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{       
    $exam_date=$rows['date'];
    $exam_time=$rows['time'];    
    echo $exam_date-date("Y-m-d"); // but it returns 0    
}
```

**how can i calculate the difference between date and time**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> echo $exam_date-date("Y-m-d"); // but it returns 0

What you do here is to subtract a string with another string.

```
echo '2015-12-09' - '2015-10-05';
```

This print `0`.

What you may want do is to use something like

```
$diff = strtotime($exam_date) - strtotime('now');
```

This get the interval seconds between two datetime.

Comment: sir how can i store both date and time in database using input field
<input type="date"> allows me to store only date  and <input type="time"> allows me to store time .i want to sotre both date and time in same column  and then want to calculate the difference b/w them

Comment: Check `datetime-local`: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime-local.html

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to work with dates and time is in MySQL. What you want can be achieved using `DATEDIFF(date1, date2)` & `TIMEDIFF(time1, time2)`

```
$query="SELECT e.*, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), `date`) as date_dif, TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIME(), `time`) as time_dif FROM exam_schedule e";
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{       
    $exam_date=$rows['date'];
    $exam_time=$rows['time'];    
    echo $rows['date_dif']; // difference in days
    echo $rows['time_dif']; // difference in hh:mm:ss
}
```

Comment: sir your answer was very helpful. it gives me my desired result. but what if i store date and time in mysql column with datatype "datetime"  (that stores both date and time in same column then what would i have to do to calculate the difference b/w current and stored time.
thanks

Comment: You can use same function `TIMEDIFF()`

Answer (score 0):

Might not be understanding what you what to do but you should be doing something like this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strototime($exam_date));
```

You can see this with PHP's [Date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) reference.

If you wish to work with time it depends on the format, if your mysql variables look like this:

```
$exam_date = '2015-10-10';
$exam_time = '22:53:00';
```

Then you can use interpolation to combine the date and time:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($exam_date." ".$exam_time));
```

Compare Database Time with now:

```
$db_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($exam_date." ".$exam_time));
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$current = $date;
$days = 0;
while ($current <= $db_date) {
  $days++;
  $current = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current)));
}
```

Comment: i am storing exam schedule in database i.e DATE 10/06/2016 TIME 10:00:AM now i want to calculate the difference between current date and time with values stored in database of date and time.

Comment: Does your TIME always have AM/PM but no seconds?

Comment: i am using <input type="time"> tag it allows only HH:MM:AM

Comment: You may want to str replace out the AM/PM and then use H:i and not H:i:s

Comment: DateTime may support the AM/PM but i'm not completely sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$currentdate = date("Y-m-d");
$date_from_db = date_create($exam_date);
$diff = date_diff($date1,$date2);
```